# How to specify input files with the geographical metadata when reading PNG files with rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I'm working with the `rasterio` library of Python to read in PNG files, manipulate them, and finally write GeoTiff files. These images are georeferenced, but the metadata with the geographical information is stored in two additional files I have obtained with other software: `file.pgw` and `file.png.aux.xml` (the name is important here, the name of the PNG is `file.png`).

Well, the issue is that the only way I have found to make `rasterio` "understanding" the image with the metadata is to use exactly the same filename and to have these three files in the same directory. This is inherited by the way GDAL work. By following this convention, the call to `rasterio.open` creates an object that not only contains the image, but also the metadata and then you can work with it, reproject etc.

But this approach inconvenient because I have several PNG files that share the same coordinates, so it's cumbersome and inefficient having to clone the `.pgw` and `.png.aux.xml` files every time I read a new PNG file. Is there a way to communicate to rasterio that the metadata is stored in a file other than `file.pgw` and `file.png.aux.xml`? Something like `rasterio.read('file.png', pgwfile = 'meta_pgw.pgw', xmlfile = 'meta_xml.xml')`? I haven't found anything like this in the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I have figured out a workaround this, in case someone gets the same issue. It is **not possible** to do what I original wanted, i.e. to specify different names for the `.pgw` and `.png.aux.xml` files. What I finally did was to use a [VRT files](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html). I use a general template (I obtained with GDAL's `gdalbuildvrt`) and then I create VRT files for each raster file using the template on the fly with Python, basically changing the name of the underlying raster file. These VRT files are XML, and therefere very lightweight. This approach, if not yet perfect, is cleaner than having to copy (or link) dummy files, so it's sufficient for my purposes.